# VBA Can't add reference to the specified Word template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

On my development machine, I began getting an error when attempting to
set a reference within a Word VBA module to another Word template. The
error was:
**Can't add a reference to the specified file.**
When I open the VBA module go to references tab I see this Word Template having **"Missing"** tag in the list.

The template I was trying to set a reference to was one I have been
using for few years without a problem.

I reinstalled MS Office, cleaned the registry of all references to the Template but nothing.

I found an workaround but is not suitable for solution.
If I open the Word template and than open the VBA module where I use it the reference will not be marked as missing.
Also if I change the VBA template name will load it successfully in the References.

Can someone give me a hand with this weird behavior? I have 2 days trying to find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Do You have any code?

Comment: Have you checked that the file is accessible via the path that is listed in References? Did your antivirus quarantine it by any chance?

Comment: @GSerg Yes I tried by path, and its not in quarantine. If i try to add it from another path works fine.

Comment: @Teamothy its not a code problem.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some kind of corruption, somewhere, based on " if I change the VBA template name will load it successfully in the References". Does this template contain anything required for your work but code? Try using the VBA Editor's File/Export to write all the contents to *bas, *.cls, etc. files (these will be in clear text). Close Word. Rename the old template. Start Word in Safe Mode (hold down Ctrl) so that you get a guaranteed "clean" Normal.dot(m). Save this as template to the required file name. In the VBA Editor import all the exported files. Save and close. Test.